# Setting the tab bar icon color when popup is shown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I was already able to set the text and icon colors for my tab bar items as desired. White for not active, blue for active.

However, I still run into one issue:
When a popover or alert view is shown, the tab bar item icon is greyed out:

[image]
[image]

Is there any possibility to keep the blue color for this state?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, but my question is not a duplicate. I already do all these things:

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = COLOR_CORPORATE_BLUE;
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   COLOR_CORPORATE_BLUE, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

NSUInteger i = 0;
NSString *imageName = @"";
for (UITabBarItem *item in self.tabBar.items) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0: imageName = @"home_tab_db"; break;
        case 1: imageName = @"home_tab_al"; break;
        case 2: imageName = @"home_tab_ru"; break;
        case 3: imageName = @"home_tab_da"; break;
    }

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    if ([img respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {
        item.image = [img imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    } else {
        item.image = img;
    }
    item.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageName stringByAppendingString:@"_active"]];

    i++;
}
```

However, as I've written, any popover, alert view, etc. will change the color of my active icon to grey.

Answer (score 6):

```
self.tabBar.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```

Does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that issue, by setting an image property. Select an image from Assets folder -> click on the particular image -> Go attribute inspector -> set Render As property to Original Image

[image]

Comment: I had my tab bar items image set to original, but once a tab bar item was selected, the image was dimmed. The solution is to use 'tintAdjustmentMode', as in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36541994/1180728