# how to stop tabbar items from turning grey when popover appears

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uitabbaritem

I am showing a popover controller in one of my view controller.

whenever the popover appears, the active tab bar item turns its color from blue to grey when the popover disappears the color turns back from grey to blue again.

I don't want active tab bar item to changes it's color with respect to Popover appearance and disappearance.

this is the default behaviour.I am able to change the shade color of popover by create backbround view class but couldn't find any such things to stop tab bar icon from changing its color.

Any helpful pointers are welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25937079/3151675

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622555-tintadjustmentmode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code snippet.It will do the job

```
self.tabbar.tintAdjustmentMode=UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```